# Update value based on value from another record of same table

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

Here I have a sample table of a website visitors. As we can see, sometimes visitor don't provide their email. Also they may switch to different email addresses over period.

**

- Original table:

**
[image]

I want to update this table with following requirements:

1. First time when a visitor provides an email, all his past visits will be tagged to that email
2. Also all his future visits will be tag to that email until he switches to another email.

**

- Expected table after update:

**
[image]

I was wondering if there is a way of doing it in Redshift or T-Sql?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you don't care about history of emails used, why don't you just save email in Users table instead of replicating in Visits table?

Comment: I do care about history of emails used. From updated table I want to prepare a list of email addresses used by this visitor at different periods

Comment: You mention "update" and "tagging" all previous visits. You only want to update records that are Null? You want to presume the email used for those visits. Your example data doesn't show user with different emails so not a complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server or Redshift, you can use a subquery to calculate the email:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(email,
                max(email) over (partition by visitor_id, grp),
                max(case when activity_date = first_email_date then email end) over (partition by visitor_id)
                )
from (select t.*,
             min(case when email is not null then activity_date end) over 
                  (partition by visitor_id order by activity_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as first_email_date,
             count(email) over (partition by visitor_id order by activity_date between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can then use this in an update:

update t
set emai = tt.imputed_email
from (select t.*,
coalesce(email,
max(email) over (partition by visitor_id, grp),
max(case when activity_date = first_email_date then email end) over (partition by visitor_id)
) as imputed_email
from (select t.*,
min(case when email is not null then activity_date end) over
(partition by visitor_id order by activity_date) as first_email_date,
count(email) over (partition by visitor_id order by activity_date) as grp
from t
) t
) tt
where tt.visitor_id = t.visitor_id and tt.activity_date = t.activity_date and
t.email is null;

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it worked like a charm. I just had to add "rows unbounded preceding" with order by statement inside the over() clause.

Comment: @Thinkpad . . . Yes.  Redshift requires that.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that the name of the table is `Visits` and the primary key of that table is made of the columns `Visitor_id` and `Activity_Date` then you can do in T-SQL following:

- using correlated subquery:

```sql
update a
set a.Email = coalesce(
  -- select the email used previously
  (
    select top 1 Email from Visits
    where Email is not null and Activity_Date < a.Activity_Date and Visitor_id = a.Visitor_id
    order by Activity_Date desc
  ),
  -- if there was no email used previously then select the email used next
  (
    select top 1 Email from Visits
    where Email is not null and Activity_Date > a.Activity_Date and Visitor_id = a.Visitor_id
    order by Activity_Date
  )
)
from Visits a
where a.Email is null;
```

- using window function to provide the ordering:

```sql
update v
set Email = vv.Email
from Visits v
  join (
    select
      v.Visitor_id,
      coalesce(a.Email, b.Email) as Email,
      v.Activity_Date,
      row_number() over (partition by v.Visitor_id, v.Activity_Date
                         order by a.Activity_Date desc, b.Activity_Date) as Row_num
    from Visits v
      -- previous visits with email
      left join Visits a
        on a.Visitor_id = v.Visitor_id
        and a.Email is not null
        and a.Activity_Date < v.Activity_Date
      -- next visits with email if there are no previous visits
      left join Visits b
        on b.Visitor_id = v.Visitor_id
        and b.Email is not null
        and b.Activity_Date > v.Activity_Date
        and a.Visitor_id is null
    where v.Email is null
  ) vv
    on vv.Visitor_id = v.Visitor_id
    and vv.Activity_Date = v.Activity_Date
where
  vv.Row_num = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. Logically your code should work and solve my problem. But I'm not able to test this logic. Currently Redshift doesn't support correlated subquery. Wondering if there is any other solution. ERROR [74:1]: (SQLSTATE: 0A000, SQLCODE: 500310): [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;

Answer (score 0):

For each visitor_id you can update the null email value with the previus non-null value. In case there is none, you will use the next non-null value.You can get those values as follows:

```
select 
    v.*, v_prev.email prev_email, v_next.email next_email
from
    visits v
    left join visits v_prev on v.visitor_id = v_prev.visitor_id 
        and v_prev.activity_date = (select max(v2.activity_date) from visits v2 where v2.visitor_id = v.visitor_id and v2.activity_date < v.activity_date and v2.email is not null)
    left join visits v_next on v.visitor_id = v_next.visitor_id 
        and v_next.activity_date = (select min(v2.activity_date) from visits v2 where v2.visitor_id = v.visitor_id and v2.activity_date > v.activity_date and v2.email is not null)
where 
    v.email is null
```

Comment: Thanks Nirani. Logically your code should work and solve my problem. But I'm not able to test this logic.
Currently Redshift doesn't support correlated subquery. Wondering if there is any other solution. 
ERROR [74:1]: (SQLSTATE: 0A000, SQLCODE: 500310): [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;